# Open File Explorer to show by date

Tags: file, search, explorer

Using Delphi XE, I want to see all files on a drive modified by date programmatically but just can't find how to code for it. No problem with an existing search, but that's not the point.

```
ShellExecute(Application.Handle,
    nil, 
    'D:\datemodified‎11-‎12-‎2019 .. ‎12-‎12-‎2019.search-ms',
    nil, 
    nil, 
    SW_NORMAL
    );
```

This is the sort of thing I'm after,

```
ShellExecute(Application.Handle,
    nil, 
    'explorer.exe', 'search-ms:query=d:\datemodified:yesterday .. today',
    nil, 
    nil, 
    SW_NORMAL
    );
```

After much searching, I can't find the correct syntax to open File Explorer and pass a query to its search box.

Any help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, after going round in circles including various grep attempts, and trying to use Quicksearch (https://github.com/nvuono/ExplorerQuickSearch), and just plain pasting in 'datemodified:yesterday .. today' into the File Explorer searchbox, it seems saving the search 'datemodifiedyesterday .. today.search-ms' does indeed work despite the colon being stripped out by Windows, thus -

ShellExecute(Application.Handle, nil, 'D:\datemodifiedyesterday .. today.search-ms', nil, nil, SW_NORMAL );

opens File Explorer and autoexecutes the search. So now I have a handy way of backing up files each day, though I might need some more buttons on my app for alternative ranges.